# incluir navbar y footer en una pagina template de wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Como estan, cree un child theme con Child Theme Configurator, y cree una pagina de nombre
front-page.php. Necesitaba crear un carrusel con javascript y todo anda bien pero no se muestran ni el Navbar ni el footer. Probe creando la pagina como Front-page.php o agregarla como template en una pagina creada en wordpress

Como tendria que hacer para que se muestren el Navbar y el Footer?

front-page.php

```
<?php /* Template Name: Pagina de inicio */ ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>front page</title>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
 </head>
 <body>

        Contenido...

       <?php wp_footer(); ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_locale_css( $uri ){
        if ( empty( $uri ) && is_rtl() && file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/rtl.css' ) )
            $uri = get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css';
        return $uri;
    }
endif;
add_filter( 'locale_stylesheet_uri', 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' );
         
if ( !function_exists( 'child_theme_configurator_css' ) ):
    function child_theme_configurator_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_child', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'astra-theme-css','woocommerce-layout','woocommerce-smallscreen','woocommerce-general' ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_configurator_css', 10 );

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION

// styles css
function add_styles() {
       agrego los estilos...                
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_styles');
   
                /**
 * Enqueue Glide.js scripts and styles.
 */
function glide_js_scripts_styles() {
    agrego javascript...
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'glide_js_scripts_styles' );
```

Comment: Qué contiene wp_head() y wp_footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te hace falta el header y el footer, agrega al principio de tu archivo

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

y al final de tu archivo

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

no necesitas llamar a `wp_head` o `wp_footer`, estos ya vienen incluidos en la plantilla de header y footer

tampoco necesitas agregar la etiqueta header o body, pues estas tambien vienen incluidas, almenos que quieras que el diseño sera completamente diferente, en ese caso tendras que diseñar un nuevo header y footer.

Esta seria la estructura correcta para una plantilla de página.

```
<?php
/*
*
* Template Name: Pagina de inicio
*
*/ 
get_header();
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <!--== Agrega tu contenido aquí ==-->

<?php 
    endwhile;
get_footer(); ?>
```